# How to apply JavaScript to bootstrap btn-group-justified to select/unselect the children button elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Okay I understand that the JavaScript is not being applied to the entire group because each button is part of a different group, but the documentation says this is the proper way to use justified with the button tag. This would not be an issue except I need them to be justified.

So my question is: how am I supposed to use JavaScript on all three buttons as a whole? It should operate as a simple radio button group.

Click one and the others are unselected. Any advice would be great!

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Low Cost/Effeciency</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Average</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">High Cost/Effeciency</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.btn-group button', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

    //other things I need to do
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button elements are not sibling elements.

You need to select the parent element's sibling elements.

[**Working Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/eakbvwxL/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-group button', function (e) {
  $(this).addClass('active').parent().siblings().find('button').removeClass('active');
});
```

However, the proper way to do this is to use the attribute `data-toggle="buttons"`.

In doing so, you don't need to write any custom JS. For more information, see  [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362750/bootstrap-button-group-pre-select-button-with-html-only) of mine explaining how it works.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" />Low Cost/Effeciency
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" />Average
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" />High Cost/Effeciency
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes much more sense.